# react redux браузер перерисовывает компонент только после случайной активности на странице

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Есть компонента. Обновляю её локальный стейт через useEffect. Данные беру из store redux. Есть нюанс с перерисовкой, с которым раньше я нигда не сталкивался.
Компонента перисовывается если соблюдено хотя бы одно из условий:

1. Открыт инспектор в браузере.
2. Если навести курсор на элемент, стили которого изменяются по hover.
3. Если поскроллить страницу
4. Если переключиться на другую уже открытую ранее вкладку браузера.
5. Если свернуть окно браузера, а затем развернуть его.
   Пробовал на firefox и googlechrome.
   Мне хотя бы знать, что за проблема, чтобы нагуглить ее. Разумеется, что по запросу "Не перерисовывается компонента react" я получаю выдачу, где у людей useEffect неверно реализован, когда у них компонента не обновляется ни при каких обстоятельствах.

Answer (score 0):

Начал откатывать все к более старым версиям.
Проблема оказалась в подключении ReactDOM в index.js
Было так. (По-новому)
[image: Был]

А сделал так. (По-старому)
[image: Стало]

P.s.прошу прощения за картинки, со смартфона нет доступа к коду. Кто хочет, может переписать и оформить в виде ответа. В этом случае свой ответ я удалю.